# Using pods with conflicting AFNetworking dependencies

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to use two pods--JGAFImageCache and ADNKit--that specify different versions of AFNetworking. Here's my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'ADNKit'
pod 'JGAFImageCache'
pod 'DerpKit'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'iOS7Colors', '~> 2.0.0'
```

When running `pod install`, I get this message:

> [!] ADNKit (1.3.1) tries to activate `AFNetworking (~> 1.3.0)', but already activated version`2.0.0-RC3' by Podfile, AFNetworking (2.0.0-RC3), AFNetworking/Core (2.0.0-RC3), AFNetworking/Core (2.0.0-RC3), AFNetworking/Core (2.0.0-RC3), and AFNetworking/Core (2.0.0-RC3).

Removing AFNetworking and relying on `v1.3.0` in ADNKit results in this:

> [!] JGAFImageCache (1.1.0) tries to activate `AFNetworking (~> 1.2.0)', but already activated version`1.3.3' by ADNKit (1.3.1).

I'd be happy working with `v1.3.1`; I don't need the latest version of AFNetworking.

How do I get JGAFImageCache and ADNKit to stop fighting over which version of AFNetworking to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, your best bet is to file an issue with those developers to use up to date dependencies.  The problem is that those pods rely on AFNetworking's API to not change, so there could be issues if you try to use a later version and some of the API has been removed.

Another approach would be to fork those repos and then change the dependencies within the podfiles yourself so that they are both using the same dependency.  Then you'd just point your app's podfile to install them from your forked repo.  This could break something, so you'll have to check for yourself and it's obviously not a good long term solution.

```
pod 'ADNKit', :git => 'https://github.com/yourUsername/ADNKit.git'
```

Comment: +1: Fork the repos and resolve the dependency differences. You can always later pull from 'upstream' into your fork as new changes occur, too.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the solution. :) Thanks for the info!